# Python: Select particular characters from a file and add them to a new variable

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I'm fairly new to python and I'm not sure why what I'm doing is wrong.

```
numberOfOrders = 0
numberOfProducts = 0

allOrders = open("file.txt", "r") #A .txt file in the same directory as the .py file.
#file.txt: 
#(A->[a:20,a:20,b:10,c:25,c:25])
#(B->[d:100,e:70])
#(C->[f:10000,g:200000])

while True:
        theline = allOrders.readline()
        for theline in allOrders:
            for char in theline: #Iterate over each character of a line.
                listProducts = "" #Empty string, will be the concatenation of the wanted characters.
                if char == "[": #Wanted character.
                    listProducts = listProducts + "["
                elif char == ":": #To keep count of no. of products in a list.
                    numberOfProducts += 1
                elif is_number(char) == True: #Function that checks whether char is a number.
                    listProducts = listProducts + str(char) #Add to the string "listProducts".
                elif char == ",": #Wanted character.
                    listProducts = listProducts + str(char)
                elif char == "]":#Wanted character, to end the string.
                    listProducts = listProducts +str(char)
                    break
            numberOfOrders += 1 #To keep track of no. of orders. Each line of file is an order. 
        if len(theline) == 0:
            break

    allOrders.close()

    print(numberOfProducts)
    print(numberOfOrders)
    print(listProducts)
```

I basically only want the numbers and commas within brackets. That's my biggest issue here.
The output I get for

```
 print(listProducts)
```

is

```
 ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could first get rid of the line "for theline in allOrders:" which seems inappropriate...

Comment: Does your text file look *exactly* like what you've shown in the comments? I.e. does it include "#(A->" and the closing parenthesis?

Comment: Add what you want the output to look like. Would that first line be `20,20,10,25,25`?

Comment: Text file _does not_ include any "#" but does include all the rest.
Output would be like: [20, 20, 10, 25, 25].

Comment: Do you mean a python list or a string that kinda looks like a python list? Strings converted to ints? It seems like what you really want is a count of orders and products. I'm going to take a wild guess.

Comment: Also you should not reinitialize listProducts to an empty string in the for loop, but rather before the while loop.

Comment: @LaurentH. Riiight. Totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Removing the first useless for loop and moving the initialization of string are sufficient to solve your problem ?

Comment: Yep, is there anyway to thank you and @tdelaney (for his also helpful solution)?

Comment: @Gitzee You can up-vote mine. And consider moving to regular expressions instead of hacking up the characters yourself. That's what its there for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code, the solution is to:

1. Removing the `for theline in allOrders` which is not coherent
2. Moving the initialization of `listProducts` before the while loop

Of course this can be widely optimized using regex for example, as suggested by @tdelaney.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the digits and commas by stripping everything else out using a regular expression. Then you have a string of decimals and commas that you can split to give a list of products in each order line.

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as all_orders:
    # substitute '' for all non-digit non-comma then split
    orders = [re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', line).split(',')
        for line in all_orders]

number_of_orders = len(orders)
number_of_products = sum(map(len, orders))
print('orders', number_of_orders, 'products', number_of_products)
```